# Initialize Facebook share button after API is loaded

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple Facebook share button which gets initialized when the Facebook API gets loaded. However if I added write the div to the document after the facebook api is loaded then it doesn't get initialized.

Is there a method I can call to initialize it after the api has been loaded?

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://mysite.com/"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use facebook api parse to force it to initialize it.

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('div_id'));
```

Comment: If you get "init not called with valid version" error, make sure u call `FB.init({ version:  'v2.7', xfbml  : false /* don't parse XFBML */ });` first.
(should only be called once after FB library is loaded).

Comment: I'm using `FB.XFBML.parse()` and it works without pass an element